# how to get the distinct values from a column using JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am trying to retrive the unique values from salary column from the database using JDBC. a little help would be enough. thank you

Comment: handle that in the query, `SELECT distinct salary FROM table_name` or `SELECT salary FROM table_name group by salary`

Comment: It is also worth noting that JDBC is agnostic of the syntax and meaning of your SQL statements.  This question is really about the SQL dialect of the database that you are using.   And you didn't say what it its.

Comment: thank you so much. both queries are working fine. but there are two thing again. 1st is how would i get the complete information of all the rows and how is second query working, because group by doesn't exclude duplicates. if you can explain,that would be helpful. i need to understand this completly.

Comment: Simply `SELECT DISTINCT`. (That group by idea is so odd...)

Answer (score 0):

```java
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,DB_USER,DB_PASSWD);

Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT salary FROM table_name");
```

Comment: this will fetch the salary from emp table. i want unique values from salary table. no duplications.

Comment: What is your query? Have you tried using "distinct" in your query?

Comment: sorry just add distinct before salary in its query

Answer (score 0):

This question is possibly duplicated, but there you go:

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT DISTINCT salary from DATATABLE", Integer.class);
```

Second argument of this method should match the type of the salary column (I assumed it was Integer but I might be wrong).